# Does overloading the function operator allows to create objects that syntactically work like functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, overloading, call, operator-keyword

I came across the following question:

> Overloading the function operator
>
> a. Requires a class with an overloaded operator.
>
> b. Requires a class with an overloaded () operator.
>
> c. Allows you to create objects that act syntactically like functions.
>
> d. Usually make use of a constructor that takes arguments.

The answer is given as (a) whereas as per my understanding, the correct answer should be (c). My logic is that operator () can be overloaded in classes as well as in structures. Hence this rules out options (a) and (b). Moreover, when operator () is overloaded, objects created will basically act like functions.

For example, if we consider the following:

```
struct A {
      void operator()(char c) { }
};

int main() {
        A a;
        a('z'); // operator() is invoked, hence  works like function
}
```

Please let me know where I am wrong in this. This question has been bugging me for a while now. Thank you

Comment: Imagine what happens if the overloaded operator is `private`.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` and `class` both create types which are classes in C++.  So that logic fails.

Like most multiple choice questions it is garbage.

"the function operator" -- ambiguous.  Maybe refers to the "function call" operator.  Or maybe a cast-to-function pointer operator.  http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/over.call as a guess.  So I'll go with that.

> c. Allows you to create objects that act syntactically like functions.

What is "like"?  No object can act syntactically identical to a function name; function names are really strange beasts in C++.  Any degree of similarity or difference could justify or counterindicate this answer.  Ambiguous nonsense.

> a. Requires a class with an overloaded operator.

Ok, true; I am unaware of a way to overload a function call without overloading an operator on a class (or using a lambda, which just does it for me).

> b. Requires a class with an overloaded () operator.

Mostly true.  Or in other words, false.

```
template<auto x>
using k=std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<dexltype(x)>,x>;
```

then

```
void foo(){}

k<foo> not_foo;
```

`not_foo` has no overloaded `operator()` yet `not_foo()` could be argued to be an overload of a function call.

It does, however, have an overloaded implicit cast to function pointer.  Which can be selectedwhen you do a function call.

So b is false, maybe.

The question splits hairs without itself being precise.  Fire instructor, get a better one.